# Wordpress wrong home URL

Tags: wordpress

Copied wordpress from localhost to server.
All links works but the home url is not working.

If I want to go to www.example.org, the website/wordpress will go to www.example.org/example (wordpress adds the domainname??)

I changed site and home url in phpmyadmin to http://www.example.org
But that didn't work. All other menu links work

Answer (score 0):

You can add this 2 lines to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

or in functions.php

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

or you have something wrong in .htaccess

Comment: just did option 1, didn't work..option 2 is a bit harder..seems there are different functions.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to mysql you can try to execute those queries in your db with a tool like phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem too a weeks ago, when move my local MAMPP site to online hosting. It was a little differet case, because after move my site online, all the page was `domain.com:8888/` (forced to the 8888 port). But I can resolve my problem by updating my db with the query as motto mentioned above.

When I see your case, maybe you don't put the website data in `/public_html/`, but in a folder `/public_html/example` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It was a cache problem of chrome.
After removing all cache en browser history it worked